# How to create a calendar dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a calendar control dynamically and I would like to add the selected date that needs to be displayed in a text box.

I need to do all this dynamically in code. I am trying it with this code here:

```
cell1.Controls.Add(new Label() {
                        ID = "Label" + childnodecount, 
                        Text = controllabel, 
                        ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
                    });
cell2.Controls.Add(new Calendar() { ID = "Calendar" + childnodecount });
cell2.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { ID = "CalendarTextBox" + childnodecount });
row.Cells.Add(cell1);
row.Cells.Add(cell2);
dynamictable.Rows.Add(row);
SearchParameter = SearchParameter + controllabel + "=" 
                + Request.Form["TextBox" + childnodecount] + "|";
```

The calendar is created, but when I select any date, all the created controls are gone from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` event.

```
public void page_load()
{ 
  //code to create objects and add them to Controls collection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Page_Load` event and Manage `IsPostBack` Property in a proper way.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if(IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created dynamic calendar in c# for this code. i think this code comfort for you.

public partial class Calender : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string[] Month = new string[]{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
        HtmlTableRow tr;
        HtmlTableCell tc;
        Button btn;
        Label lbl;

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control control in ph1.Controls)
        {
            ph1.Controls.Remove(control);
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["Calander"] = null;
            var dt = new DateTime(System.DateTime.Now.Year, System.DateTime.Now.Month, 01);
            var dttable = new DataTable();
            dttable.Columns.Add("type", typeof (string));
            dttable.Columns.Add("value", typeof (DateTime));
            var dr = dttable.NewRow();
            dr["type"] = "M-Y";
            dr["value"] = dt;
            dttable.Rows.Add(dr);

            GenerateTable(dttable);

            for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
            {
                ddlday.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
            }
            ddlmonth.DataSource = Month;
            ddlmonth.DataBind();
        }
        for (int i = 1900; i < DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
        {
            ddlyear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        }
        if (Session["Calander"] != null)
        {
            var dtSession = (DataTable) Session["Calander"];
            GenerateTable(dtSession);
        }
    }

    private void GenerateTable(DataTable dtSession)
    {
        foreach (Control c in ph1.Controls)
        {
            ph1.Controls.Remove(c);
        }

        var datesession = new DateTime();
        if (dtSession.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            datesession = Convert.ToDateTime(dtSession.Rows[0]["value"]);
        }
        var count = 0;

        var tb1 = new HtmlTable();
        tb1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth,"1px");
        tb1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
        tb1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");

        tr = new HtmlTableRow();
        tb1.Rows.Add(tr);

        tc = new HtmlTableCell();
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth,"1px");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "left");
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        btn = new Button();
        btn.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign,"left");
        btn.ID = "btnmonpre";
        btn.Text = "<<";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnmonpre_Click); 
        tc.Controls.Add(btn);

        tc = new HtmlTableCell();
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
        if (dtSession.Rows[0]["type"].ToString() == "M-Y")
        {
            tc.ColSpan = 5;
        }
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "btnmonyear";

        if (Convert.ToString(dtSession.Rows[0]["type"]) == "M-Y")
        {
            btn.Text = Month[datesession.Month - 1] + "-" + datesession.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        tc.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(BtnMonYear_clicl);

        tc = new HtmlTableCell();
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
        tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "right");
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        btn = new Button();
        btn.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "right");
        btn.ID = "btnmonnext";
        btn.Text = ">>";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnmonnext_Click);
        tc.Controls.Add(btn);

        if (dtSession.Rows[0]["type"].ToString() == "M-Y")
        {
            int startPoint = 0, endPoint = 0, DatePlaceCount = 0;
            var firstDate = new DateTime(datesession.Year,datesession.Month,01);
            startPoint = (int) firstDate.DayOfWeek;

            if (startPoint == 0)
            {
                startPoint = 7;
            }
            endPoint = firstDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day;

            int previousDays = firstDate.AddDays(-1).Day;
            int pDatePlace = previousDays - (startPoint - 2);
            int nDatePlace = 1; 

            tr = new HtmlTableRow();
            tb1.Rows.Add(tr);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day1";
            lbl.Text = "Mon";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day2";
            lbl.Text = "Tue";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day3";
            lbl.Text = "Wed";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");  
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day4";
            lbl.Text = "Thu";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px"); 
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day5";
            lbl.Text = "Fri";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day6";
            lbl.Text = "Sat";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tc = new HtmlTableCell();
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "1px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
            tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.ID = "day7";
            lbl.Text = "Sun";
            tc.Controls.Add(lbl);

            tb1.Rows.Add(tr);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                tr = new HtmlTableRow();
                tb1.Rows.Add(tr);

                for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    tc = new HtmlTableCell();
                    tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth,"1px");
                    tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderStyle, "solid");
                    tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderColor, "black");
                    tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
                    tc.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.TextAlign, "center");
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    count++;

                    if (count >= startPoint && count < startPoint + endPoint) // current month dateplace
                    {
                        DatePlaceCount++;
                        btn = new Button();
                        btn.Text = DatePlaceCount.ToString();
                        btn.ID = btn + count.ToString();
                        btn.EnableViewState = false;
                        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);
                        tc.Controls.Add(btn);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (count < startPoint) // Previous month
                        {
                            btn = new Button();
                            btn.Text = pDatePlace.ToString();
                            btn.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Red");
                            btn.ID = btn + count.ToString();
                            btn.ValidationGroup = "Prev";
                            btn.EnableViewState = false;
                            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);
                            tc.Controls.Add(btn);
                            pDatePlace++;
                        }
                        else if (count >= startPoint + endPoint) // Next month
                        {
                            btn = new Button();
                            btn.Text = nDatePlace.ToString();
                            btn.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Blue");
                            btn.ID = btn + count.ToString();
                            btn.ValidationGroup = "Next";
                            btn.EnableViewState = false;
                            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);
                            tc.Controls.Add(btn);
                            nDatePlace++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ph1.Controls.Add(tb1);
            Session["Calander"] = null;
            dtSession.Rows.Clear();
            DataRow dr = dtSession.NewRow();
            dr["type"] = "M-Y";
            dr["value"] = new DateTime(firstDate.Year, firstDate.Month, firstDate.Day);
            dtSession.Rows.Add(dr);
            Session["Calander"] = dtSession;
        }
    }

    protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dt = new DateTime();
        //var dt1 = DateTime.TryParse(ddlyear.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "/" + Array.IndexOf(Month, ddlmonth.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) + 1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "/" + ddlday.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), out dt);
        var year = ddlyear.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var month = Convert.ToInt32(Array.IndexOf(Month, ddlmonth.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))) + 1;
        var date = ddlday.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var dt1 = DateTime.Parse(month + "/" + date + "/" + year);
        if (dt1 != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            if (Session["Calander"] != null)
            {
                Session["Calander"] = null;
                // DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), Convert.ToInt32(ddlmonth.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), Convert.ToInt32(ddlday.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
                dtTable.Columns.Add("type", typeof(string));
                dtTable.Columns.Add("value", typeof(DateTime));
                DataRow dr = dtTable.NewRow();
                dr["type"] = "M-Y";
                dr["value"] = dt1;
                dtTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                GenerateTable(dtTable);
                Response.Write(" U R Selecting Date:" + dt1.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));

                // var dtSession = (DataTable)Session["Calander"];
                // GenerateTable(dtSession);


            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnmonpre_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtsession = (DataTable)Session["Calander"];
        DateTime datesession = Convert.ToDateTime(dtsession.Rows[0]["value"]);

        if (Convert.ToString(dtsession.Rows[0]["type"]) == "M-Y")
        {
            if (datesession.AddMonths(-1).Year >= 1970)
            {
                dtsession.Rows[0]["value"] = datesession.AddMonths(-1);
            }
            Session["Calander"] = dtsession;
            GenerateTable(dtsession);
        }
    }

    protected void btnmonnext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        DataTable dtsession = (DataTable)Session["Calander"];
        DateTime datesession = Convert.ToDateTime(dtsession.Rows[0]["value"]);

        if (Convert.ToString(dtsession.Rows[0]["type"]) == "M-Y")
        {
            if (datesession.AddMonths(1).Year <= 2070)
            {
                dtsession.Rows[0]["value"] = datesession.AddMonths(1);
            }
            Session["Calander"] = dtsession;
            GenerateTable(dtsession);
        }
    }

    protected void BtnMonYear_clicl(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtSession = (DataTable)Session["Calander"];
        DateTime datesession = (DateTime)dtSession.Rows[0]["value"];
        if (dtSession.Rows[0]["type"].ToString() == "M-Y")
        {
            dtSession.Clear();
            DataRow dr = dtSession.NewRow();
            dr["type"] = "M-Y";
            dr["value"] = datesession;
            dtSession.Rows.Add(dr);
            Session["Calander"] = dtSession;
            GenerateTable(dtSession);
        }
    }

    protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        DataTable dtsession = (DataTable)Session["Calander"];
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        DateTime ResultDate;
        DateTime dt;
        if (Convert.ToString(dtsession.Rows[0]["type"]) == "M-Y")
        {
            if (b.ValidationGroup == "Prev")
            {
                dt = (DateTime)(dtsession.Rows[0]["value"]);
                dt = dt.AddMonths(-1);
                ResultDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, Convert.ToInt32(b.Text));
                b.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green");
                Response.Write("U R Selecting Date:" + ResultDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
            }
            else if (b.ValidationGroup == "Next")
            {
                dt = (DateTime)(dtsession.Rows[0]["value"]);
                dt = dt.AddMonths(1);
                ResultDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, Convert.ToInt32(b.Text));
                b.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green");
                Response.Write(" U R Selecting Date:" + ResultDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
            }
            else
            {
                dt = (DateTime)(dtsession.Rows[0]["value"]);
                ResultDate = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, Convert.ToInt32(b.Text));
                b.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Green");
                Response.Write(" U R Selecting Date:" + ResultDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```